# action lifecycle

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm looking for a documentation page where wordpress action lifecycle is explained. Does it exist?

I can't understand if init is called before admin_head or viceversa (even if the name is auto-explenatory in this case)

Answer (score 5):

The order and appearance of actions depend on the page and the loaded files.

[`get_search_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form) for example fires an action `'get_search_form'` and (oddly enough) also a filter `'get_search_form'`. But if no search form is loaded the action will not be available.

The only way to really *know* which actions are available is to look at them on different pages. There is a magic action `'all'` to hook into … well … *all* actions.
My plugin [All Actions List](https://gist.github.com/1979171) does exactly this. It prints all actions found into the footer on the last action named `'shutdown'` which is always available.

On the front page of a simple blog, there are ~2300 actions – including filters which may be used as actions too.

Comment: what about admininistration pages? is there any standard action flows?

Comment: There is no defined standard. `admin_init` is usually there, `'admin_head'` and `'admin_footer'` too.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a list (in order) of the actions that get run during a typical page request in WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request

Note that many actions are called multiple times at various times in the code. There is no such thing as a “one true linear action chain”.

Comment: the list under "Actions Run During a Typical Request " section reprents the ordered action calls, doesn't it?